# Unable to use ASP.NET Core SignalR with more than one user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, azure-signalr

I am having a problem on my chat website when running Azure SignalR with more than 1 user. e.g.

User A logs into the system and can send/receive messages fine, User B logs in too and gets a JavaScript error. If User A closes the browser window then User B can send/receive messages fine, and vice versa.

This is the tech that i am using:

- ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET Framework Runtime)
- Microsoft.Azure.SignalR v1.0.3 (free tier)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR
- JS Client - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@@aspnet/signalr@1.0.3/dist/browser/signalr.min.js

The error seems to come from the SignalR Javascript client.

This is the Google Chrome console error message that i get:

[image]

My JS code looks like this:

```
function setChatConnection() {
    var chatConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('/chat')
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .build();
    bindConnectionMessage(chatConnection);
    chatConnection.start()
        .then(function () {
             chatConnection.send('joingroup');
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
        });
}
```

I did some debugging and it seemed to get into the chatConnection.send('joingroup') method before the error occurred, though i think this is a red herring, i added some debugging to the OnConnectedAsync method in the hub and can confirm that it is also not called.

My hub doesn't have anything fancy, i added some logging and it looks like the hub may not be getting called when the second user tries to use the chat

```
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public async void JoinGroup()
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "Test");
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  I have also tried upgrading to the paid Azure SignalR tier, but still get the same issue.

Comment: Are User1 and User2 on the same PC or different PCs?

Comment: Different PCs at 2 different locations

Comment: what is `chatConnection.send('joingroup');` doing can we see the backend code for that

Comment: Hi, I added some additional info in the question, i think the chatConnection.send('joingroup'); is a red herring, i added some logging an OnConnectedAsync is also not called for the second user that arrives on the chat page